# How to customize buttons in ArcPAD?

Tags: arcpad

When I measure a points with trimble GPS can I make a shortcut on a BUTTON in ArcPad to measure POINT(capture point) from a GPS? I don't want to have to always take the little "pen" and click on a CAPTURE POINT. Instead I want to click it with finger on some of buttons on ArcPad. I find this much easier because I have to measure 400 points every day. Is it possible to customize that? Please answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ArcPad 10 you can try the following:

1. From the [QuickCapture tab in the Table of Contents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#//00s10000007w000000#ESRI_SECTION1_AEDD74C359B643B9B29CC4108633CF48) select the features you want to tap to be editable - if the GPS is on these features are automatically captured, otherwise you'll have to capture them by tapping on the map
2. You can then [increase the button size](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/Steps_to_modify_the_standard_toolbars/00s10000012v000000/) by opening the *Quick Access Menu* then *Toolbar Settings* and then *Toolbars*
3. Lastly restart ArcPad and you should be good to go

Comment: Perfect ans : )